# BlackBerry wallpaper setting via code

Tags: blackberry, wallpaper

I need help regarding changing the wallpaper programmatically in BlackBerry.  Is there any code available for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a class [HomeScreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html)

Use it and its method [setBackgroundImage(String path2ImageFile)](http://tinyurl.com/8ehrz4y).